# Problems with multiple variable socket.io emits

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I followed a couple questions about a similar question, however, the questions and their appropriate solutions were from multiple years ago, and since then socket.io has seen several updates which make their code unusable. I've tried adapting it to fit v2.3.0 but it does not work.

I'm trying to make a chat application which has several variables that I'm trying to emit with each io.emit event (picture, name, tag, message, etc.)

At the moment, my server-side code looks as such:

```
    socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
        io.emit('chatMessage', { sendmessage: msg, sendname: username, sendertag: tag, postpiclink: userpiclink });
        console.log('message: ' + sendmessage + sendname + sendertag + postpiclink);
    });
```

There is obviously more than just this but this is the only relevant code and the rest of it functions as it should. On my client side, each event sends all the variables (I believe) along with the event. It looks as such:

```
    var userName = "<?=$_SESSION['userName'];?>"
    var userTag = "<?php if($userRank == 7) { echo "[Owner]";} elseif ($userRank == 3) { echo "[Mod]";} elseif ($userRank == 5) { echo "[Admin]";} else {}?>"
    var userPicture = "<?=$userPicture?>"
            $('.chatMessageSubmitForm').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                socket.emit('chatMessage', { message: $('#messageField').val(), username: userName, tag: userTag, userpiclink: userPicture});
                $('#messageField').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
                $('.chatMessageList').append($('<li><img src="'+ postpiclink + '"class="chatMessageUserPicture"><h2 class="chatUserName">' + sendertag + sendname + '</h2>').text(sendmessage));
            });
```

As far as I'm aware this should be formatted correctly, however when I try to send a chat message the following message appears on my server terminal:

```
io.emit('chatMessage', { sendmessage: msg, sendname: username, sendertag: tag, postpiclink: userpiclink });

ReferenceError: username is not defined
```

I'm not entirely braindead so obviously it isn't receiving the username variable when the socket emits it, but I have no clue why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to show us where the `username` variable is defined and what code is supposed to set it before you call this `io.emit()`.  You haven't shown us any of that code so we have no idea why it's not defined other than you never defined the variable in this scope.  I hope you realize that receiving some data via socket.io does not automatically define any variables that you can just reference like you are with `username`.

Comment: Are you supposed to be referencing `msg.username` instead of just `username`?

Comment: Possibly? Is socket io taking the whole object that the socket emits and putting setting it to msg? I did show where the username variable is defined, at least the part that matters, on the webpage when inspected those variables take the value they need to have, so those aren't the issue. I suspect you're onto something with msg.username so I'll double check if any tweaks to that will fix the issue. Will update shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this in the client:

```
socket.emit('chatMessage', { message: $('#messageField').val(), username: userName, tag: userTag, userpiclink: userPicture});
```

That means that when you receive it in the server here:

```
 socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', { sendmessage: msg, sendname: username, sendertag: tag, postpiclink: userpiclink });
    console.log('message: ' + sendmessage + sendname + sendertag + postpiclink);
 });
```

That means that `msg` will be the entire object you sent.  So, if you want the username from that object, you need to refer to:

```
msg.username
```

not just

```
username
```

So, you would change to this:

```
socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', { sendmessage: msg, sendname: msg.username, sendertag: msg.tag, postpiclink: msg.userpiclink });
    console.log('message: ' + sendmessage + sendname + sendertag + postpiclink);
});
```

FYI, it's redundant to be sending the entire `msg` object and then also be sending three individual properties again all in the same message.  You're essentially sending those three properties twice.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to comment after your initial comment on the post but I changed it with the msg.username extension and it worked as intended, but thank you a lot for the help!